# Product of two factors is positive iff each factor is positive or each is negative

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

Is it true that
$$
ab>0\iff (a>0 \wedge b>0)\vee (a<0\wedge b<0)$$
in general, where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$? I am pretty sure that the direction $\impliedby$ is true, but I do not know if the other direction holds. I tried proving it by contrapositive: $$\neg [(a>0 \wedge b>0)\vee (a<0\wedge b<0)]\iff \left\{\begin{matrix}
a=0, \text{ or } \\ 
b=0, \text{ or } \\ 
a\geq 0 \text{ and } b\leq 0, \text{ or } \\ 
a\leq 0 \text{ and } b\geq 0.
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
Each of them implies that $ab\leq 0$.

**Edit**: The reason I am asking is, how would you solve an inequality, say $(x-2)(x+1)>0$? Googling about it, they usually start with solving the equation $(x-2)(x+1)=0$ using the zero product property, and then analyzing the inequality with the roots. I dislike that method. I would do something like,
\begin{align*}
(x-2)(x+1)>0&\overset{?}\iff (x>2 \wedge x>-1)\vee (x<2 \wedge x<-1)\\
&\iff (x>2)\vee (x<-1)\\
&\iff x\in (-\infty,-1)\cup (2,\infty).
\end{align*}

Comment: it is indeed true $neg*neg = pos$ /// $pos*pos=pos$ /// $neg*pos=neg$ /// $pos*neg=neg$

Comment: @jorgeegroj That's what I used it for the implication $\impliedby$, but I just am not sure about the other direction.

Comment: By absurd? You can rule out $a = 0$ and $b = 0$ pretty soon, because either of them holding would yield $ab = 0$ which contradicts $ab > 0$. Now fix $a > 0$ and assume that $b < 0$: can $ab > 0$? ...

Comment: you ask for the *sign-chart method* in your edit, please see http://www.fmaths.com/signcharts/lesson.php

Comment: Your method of solving $(x-2)(x+1)>0$ is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Hopeless the two ending in $pos$ make one way of the implication true whereas the other two make the other way also true. Also, your method is perfectly fine. Just saw the edit and you're perfectly right in checking for the domain in which x satisfies the equation :)

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed true for any *real* $a$ and $b$. You can see this in both directions by examining all possible cases:
$$
a<0, \ \ b<0 \qquad a<0, \ \ b=0 \qquad a<0, \ \ b>0 
$$
$$
a=0, \ \ b<0 \qquad a=0, \ \ b=0 \qquad a=0, \ \ b>0 
$$
$$
a>0, \ \ b<0 \qquad a>0, \ \ b=0 \qquad a>0, \ \ b>0 
$$
(In the above table, only the top left and bottom right cases correspond to positive products $ab$.)

Once we go to complex numbers, things get more interesting: we might have a real positive product $ab$ for non-real $a$ and $b$, for example: $a=i, \ \ b=-i$.